# how to get an openstack token and validate it?

Tags: token, identity, openstack

I followed this guide: http://keystone.openstack.org/api_curl_examples.html

and it seemed that I got a valid token by ran:

```
curl -d '{"auth":{"passwordCredentials":{"username": "can", "password": "mypassword"}}}' -H "Content-type: application/json" http://url:35357/v2.0/tokens
```

and it returned:

```
{
"access": 
{
    "token": 
    {
        "expires": "2012-05-21T14:35:17Z", 
        "id": "468da447bd1c4821bbc5def0498fd441"
    }, 
    "serviceCatalog": {}, 
    "user": 
    {
        "username": "can",
        "roles_links": [],
        "id": "bb6d3a09ad0c4924bf20c1a32ccb5781",
        "roles": [],
        "name": "can"
    }
}
}
```

but when I came to the next few sections to validate this token, I encountered this magic number: `X-Auth-Token:999888777666`. **At first I thought it's the token I got but I was wrong.**

I think I may have missed something, so I read related sections in openstack documents( http://keystone.openstack.org/configuration.html and http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-compute/programmer/content/ ), but still no idea how the number comes from.

could anyone explain to me

1. what's the meaning of that magic number
2. how to get the right value of it so I can get a working token to manage other parts of openstack

Comment: Is it possible to requesting by ajax not by curl .. ?

Answer (score 9):

That magic number (string really) is the admin_token setting in your keystone.conf file. Under the [DEFAULT] section in keystone.conf set

```
admin_token = abcd1234
```

If you don't use it for admin actions, you'll see something like

```
ubuntu@i-000004bc:~/devstack$ curl http://localhost:35357/v2.0/tenants
{"error": {"message": "The request you have made requires authentication.", "code": 401, "title": "Not Authorized"}}
```

If you do use it, you'll see something like

```
ubuntu@i-000004bc:~/devstack$ curl -H "X-Auth-Token: abcd1234" http://localhost:35357/v2.0/tenants
{"tenants_links": [], "tenants": [{"enabled": true, "description": null, "name": "demo", "id": "aee8a46babcb4e4286021c8f6ef996cd"}, {"enabled": true, "description": null, "name": "invisible_to_admin", "id": "de17fea45de148ada0a58e998e6c3e73"}, {"enabled": true, "description": null, "name": "admin", "id": "f34b0c8ab30e450489b121fbe723fde5"}, {"enabled": true, "description": null, "name": "service", "id": "fbe3e2e530fd47298cb2cba1b4afa3da"}]}
```

Comment: Note that if you have a valid username with an admin role in a tenant, you can use that username and password to retrieve a temporary token that will allow admin actions.

Answer (score 2):

To get the list of tenants, in our current implementation, we authenticate with admin credentials and use the token returned to get list of tenants.
The implementation works smooth with the authentication token. It may work with admin_token but I have not verified.

If you see the examples you are referring to, there are 2 types of endpoints used

1. Endpoint pointing to port 5000 - public port
2. Endpoint pointing to port 35357 - admin  port

In examples which are hitting admin port you would need to specify the "X-Auth-Token" header as the admin_token (specified in the keystone.conf file)

Answer (score 1):

The token itself is in `dict["access"]["token"]["id"]` which is that part that will go in the header of subsequent HTTP requests, i.e

```
X-Auth-Token: 468da447bd1c4821bbc5def0498fd441
```

The value 999888777666 is from the curl example tutorial and will definitely not work.

As for the value of the token itself, it's randomly generated by the OpenStack service and shouldn't contain any useful information from your point of view.

(BTW, you probably shouldn't go pasting the tokens into forums as they're valid for 24 hours and anyone with a copy of the token and access to your compute endpoint can use it to impersonate you).

Comment: I said it's not the token. I tried this way:

curl -H "X-Auth-Token: 468da447bd1c4821bbc5def0498fd441" http://url:35357/v2.0/tokens/468da447bd1c4821bbc5def0498fd441

and got a 401 not authorized

Comment: Hrm - yeah the origin of the 999* token doesn't make a lot of sense in the docs.  The curl request above should work, although the http://keystone.openstack.org/api_curl_examples.html tutorial seems to imply that you must connect with an admin account to access the /tokens resource.  Can you access any other things with your token?  e.g url:35357/v2.0/tenants